# too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c

Im doing a project for school and this is the warning that keeps bugging me.
Whats wrong with my code?

```
fprintf(fp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", Item[i]->ID, Item[i]->Date, Item[i]->Adress,
                                       Item[i]->Street number, Item[i]->Postal Code,
                                       Item[i]->City, Item[i]->Phone,Item[i]->Name,
                                       Item[i]->Price);
```

Also there is another warning:

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 10
>   has type 'char *' [-Wformat]

I don't know what to do

Comment: You are missing one %s, assuming all variables are what you say they are.

Comment: Thanks man, the warning disapeared. I needed to hurry with this code so guess i missed one %s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `fprintf` call has 8 format specifiers but passes 9 further arguments to fill these.

The 8th format specifier is `%d`; the argument corresponding to this is `Item[i]->Name`.  The warning is telling you that `Item[i]->Name` is a string so can't (shouldn't) be converted to a signed integer.

I presume `Item[i]->Price` has type `int`; you then either need to add an extra `%s` to your format string (anywhere before the `%d`) or remove one of the string arguments.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner at this. Please tell me what to change in this? I need all those arguments for it to work so is there some other function that i could add?

Comment: See my updated answer.  If you want to display all these arguments, you need to add an extra format specified.  dd an extra `%s\n` anywhere before the `%d` in your format string.

Comment: Yea i saw that when i looked for similar issues. Still have problems to navigate in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your fprintf call has 8 format specifiers but passes 9 further arguments to fill these.

The 8th format specifier is %d; the argument corresponding to this is Item[i]->Name. The warning is telling you that Item[i]->Name is a string so can't (shouldn't) be converted to a signed integer.

I presume Item[i]->Price has type int; you then either need to add an extra %s to your format string (anywhere before the %d) or remove one of the string arguments.